# VBA Conditional Format if both conditions met

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Conditional Format Code is working for each condition individually, but not if both are conditions are met. If both Conditions are met the only issue is column L doesn't highlight yellow:

```
Dim Cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition
Set Cond1 = Range("L" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual,EmployeeInformation.ChiResident.Value = True)
Set cond2 = Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, x1equal, EmployeeInformation.Apprentice.Value = True)
With Cond1
.Font.Color = vbRed
.Font.Bold = True
End With
With cond2
.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
```

I have tried a few ways to get this to work if both conditions are met.  Basically do the same thing but highlight whole range in yellow and have bold red text in column L.

Attempt 1:

```
  With Cond1 And Cond2
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Color = vbRed And .Font.Bold = True And .Interior.Color = vbYellow
Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
```

Attempt 2:

```
If Cond1 And Cond2 = True Then
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Color = vbRed
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Bold = True
Range("L" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
```

Attempt 3:

```
Dim Cond1 As FormatCondition, Cond2 As FormatCondition, Cond3 As FormatCondition
Set Cond1 = Range("L" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, EmployeeInformation.ChiResident.Value = True)
Set Cond2 = Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, x1equal, EmployeeInformation.Apprentice.Value = True)
Set Cond3 = Range("L" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, EmployeeInformation.ChiResident.Value = True) And Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, x1equal, EmployeeInformation.Apprentice.Value = True)
With Cond1
.Font.Color = vbRed
.Font.Bold = True
End With
With Cond2
.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
With Cond3
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Color = vbRed
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Bold = True
Range("L" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
```

Comment: Conditional formatting works from top to bottom, where only one format will apply and if a format has been applied, it leaves the selection... kind of like `Select Case`.  If you want to have multiple conditions, you would need an `And()` and have both scenarios combined as its own condition, and set to the top of all conditions.

Comment: So why doesn't my attempt #3 work?  I thought i did that?  Did i just not code it correctly?

Comment: Check the order they appear in the list for conditional formats.

Comment: Looks like you have `x1equal`

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to VBA what does x1equal mean should i be using a different expression?  These values are pulled from a user form that has checkbox's.  So i used x1equal = True if checkbox is clicked.

Comment: @keef2 ["L" versus "1" is the issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlformatconditionoperator).

Comment: I have l not 1.  For attempt #3 i get an error `438` Object doesnt support this propety or method.  Here is my cond 3 currently: `Set Cond3 = Range("L" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, EmployeeInformation.ChiResident.Value = True) And Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, EmployeeInformation.Apprentice.Value = True)`

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question of the author entirely, as some information is missing, but it shows a way of working in order to solve the issue.

I would advise you to check the conditional formatting rules, as your VBA macro has created them. And even then, you might be faced with a bug, like in my case:

In order to check how conditional formatting works with different rules, I have created conditional formatting with two rules, who are both correct (the value of "B2" equals 5, and I use the formulas `=B2>1` and `=B2<8`. Nevertheless the second rule never gets applied, which look like a bug, as you can see here:

[image]

(Although the checkbox "Stop if True" is not clicked, it looks like the conditional formatting stops after the first rule.)

So: check your rules, using the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager, and only if this is not clear, you can suspect a bug in the conditional formatting feature.

Comment: The case you present **is not a bug** as it is documented in the help. I don't have English help docs, but goes like this: **One rule**: if two rules are contradicting, rule application stops at first rule that is a match. The docs even presents an example situation exactly similar to yours. **Another rule**: The `Stop if True` tick boxes are there to simulate behavior of older (than 2007) excels, which only allowed three rules.